# Why does the RetryScheduler in Axon Framework not retry after a NoHandlerForCommandException?

Tags: java, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

so I have a Saga and the Saga sends a command to a different microservice on a specific event. I wanted to configure the commandGateway with a RetryScheduler, so that it retries to send the command in case that the other microservice is down. The RetryScheduler will only perform retries if the exception is a RuntimeException, which the NoHandlerForCommandException that  is thrown when the other service if offline definately is.

If i dont set the maxRetryCount then the error message is 
 o.a.c.gateway.IntervalRetryScheduler : Processing of Command [XXXCommand] resulted in an exception 1 times. Giving up permanently

If I do set the attribute the error message is 
o.a.c.gateway.IntervalRetryScheduler : Processing of Command [XXXCommand] resulted in an exception and will not be retried

If the other microservice is running, then the command is handled correctly, no problems.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the issue?

This is my configuration for the commandGateway with a RetryScheduler:

```
@Bean
public CommandGateway commandGateway(){

    Configurer configurer = DefaultConfigurer.defaultConfiguration();

    CommandBus commandBus = configurer.buildConfiguration().commandBus();

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    RetryScheduler rs = IntervalRetryScheduler.builder().retryExecutor(scheduledExecutorService).maxRetryCount(100).retryInterval(1000).build();
    CommandGateway commandGateway = DefaultCommandGateway.builder().commandBus(commandBus).retryScheduler(rs).build();

    return commandGateway;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I just saw that in fact the NoHandlerForCommandException is a AxonNonTransientException and will not be retried....so what  would be the best approach here? I want the command to retry, so once the service which handles the command comes back up will actually execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem at hand, you could provide your own implementation of the `IntervalRetryScheduler`, which overrides the `IntervalRetryScheduler#isExplicitlyNonTransient(Throwable)` method to also take into account retrying the `NoHandlerForCommandException`.

Note though that the `IntervalRetryScheduler` is intentionally only retrying on exceptions which are of type `AxonNonTransientException`, is those typically signal recoverable exceptions. The `NoHandlerForCommandException` means that the `CommandBus` implementation being used has no clue whom to give the command too, something which in general suggests an thing which cant be retried.

It however seems you have a scenario where it does make sense. Thus, like I point out at the start, overriding the `isExplicitlyNonTransient(Throwable)` method to exclude `NoHandlerForCommandException` would be the way to go for you I think.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: This should definately do but feels kinda like a dirty workaround. Doesn't axon offer an out-of-the-box solution for such a basic problem? If a microservice that is not available and not currently connected to axon server handles the command of a different microservice. Is there a special commandBus version or something more suited in that scenario?

Comment: I do feel that it should be easier to configure which exceptions should be taken into account. But, I'd personally state it's better suited to ensure that the given microservice is more fault tolerant than that this should be covered by the framework. Especially when utilizing Axon Server it is _no issue at all_ to instantiate several instances of the given microservice to handle the command in question. If one or all of them are down that signals a very big problem in the setup. I don't think I'd want the command dispatcher to recover from that itself to be honest.

Comment: Granted, it always depends on the use case at hand, so you might just have the sensible scenario where this *is* needed. Any how, there is no special implementation of the `CommandBus` provided by the framework to hold off on commands not being delivered because of the none existence of a command handler for it.

Hope this sheds some light on the situation.